# Android Gradle Error - Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class

Tags: android, utf-8, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

From one day to the other I opened the Android project that I'm currently working on and I got this gradle error, also happens when I try to create a new project:

**Gradle sync failed: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file com/android/build/gradle/tasks/RenderscriptCompile$_ConfigAction_execute_closure7**

Also I noticed that the arrangement of all the app packages has changed to this configuration and it is not able to import AppCompactActivity:

[Error print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbzSM.png)

I had been trying to find something on the web but so far I found nothing related to this specific case. I tried a few things myself but I think it only made it even worse..

Anyone out there that can help me?

Thanks!

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.*****.musicpad"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: It look like one of the layout xml has a error...please check it properly

Comment: I did some updates both on my windows and on the SDK Manager, and it somehow solved it out. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this error i have solved it by deleting the temp files.
Control panel-->Java-->Settings-->delete files and restore defaults.

[image: How to open java settings and delete temp files]